# Linq equivalent of the T_SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
SELECT Employees.EmployeeId,Employees.FirstName,Employees.LastName
FROM   Database.dbo.Employees Employees
where Employees.FirstName not in
(select FirstName from Customers)    
and LastName not in(select LastName from Customers) and IsEmployeeActive=1

union

select CustomerId,FirstName,LastName from Customers
```

I am total newbie to LINQ-SQL and trying to learn it.

This is what I have tried(still working)..I am sure there is a better way:

```
 var innerQuery = from user in Database.Customers
                         select new
                                    {
                                        Customer.CustomerID,
                                        Customer.FirstName,
                                        Customer.LastName
                                    };

        var userQuery = (from employee in Database.Employees
                         from customer in Database.Customers
                         where
                             employee.FirstName.ToLower().Trim() != customer.FirstName.ToLower().Trim() &&
                             employee.LastName.ToLower().Trim() != customer.LastName.ToLower().Trim()
                         select new
                                    {
                                        employee.EmployeeId,
                                        employee.FirstName,
                                        employee.LastName
                                    });

      var test=  innerQuery.Union(userQuery);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far and had it not work?

Comment: Actually trying few things....I have updated the query to reflect it

Comment: I gave you a vb version below before you updated your post and showed you're working with c#.  I've retagged your question so you might get more looks.

Comment: lazyDBA has already answered. I find using [linkpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) really useful to test LINQ queries

Comment: Are you sure you want `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: You bring up an point worth mentioning.  The SQL union only joins unique values.  Union All joins them all.  Based on the query posted above it appears the user only wants unique entries, unless there is another reason for the use of "firstname not in and lastname not in".  With that said the LINQ union behaves the same.  It only returns unique entries.  So, if that really is what the poster intends, the union takes care of that aspect for him.

Comment: @lazyDBA since he Union'ing CustomerID with EmployeeId (different pk's), I suspect he actually wants a `Union All` (`Concat` in Linq)

Answer (score 2):

If this is something you'll be regularly running the simplest approach would be to put that query into a view.  Then the LINQ syntax on the view is easy.

If you have your heart set on figuring out the LINQ then work it out here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688085  (vb samples)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx  (c# samples)

This VB approach will be very close but will need some debugging since it's off top o my head.

```
    Dim q = (From e In db.Employees Where e.IsEmployeeActive=1 _
    Select EntityID = e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName, e.LastName).Union(From c In db.Customers _
    Select EntityID = c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName)
```

Comment: I took the Distinct() off, as I realized the presence of a Union statement would automatically ensure only distinct values were returned.

Comment: Your union'ing  Employees with itself. Also not taking into account the `FirstName not in...` and `IsEmployeeActive`

Comment: Good call on querying employees twice, that was typo.  As for the "NOT IN" ... using a union automically ignores anything that is a duplicate meeting that need.  It doesn't require the "NOT IN" clause.

Comment: Not really since we are union'ing on EmployeeId and CustomerID also

Answer (score 2):

```
var q = 
  (from employee in Database.Employees
  where !Database.Customers.Any(c => employee.FirstName == c.FirstName) &&
    employee.IsEmployeeActive
  select new
  {
    employee.EmployeeId,
    employee.FirstName,
    employee.LastName
  }).Union(
  from customer in Database.Customers
  select new
  {
    customer.CustomerID,
    customer.FirstName,
    customer.LastName
  });
```

Comment: I voted yours up one for the good call on employeeid != customerid on my post.